# Any idea what (0, _jquery["default"]) means in terms of jQuery selector or function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get some jQuery working on an offline page. The site's app uses EmberJS, RequireJS, and who knows what else, but the bottom line is I am trying to replace this cryptic code with plain jQuery.

Here is some HTML that should respond to interaction:

Loading interaction...
        
            RevealContent
            
            
                
                    
                        
                        ***Some question***
                    
                
                
                    
                        **Some answer**

So it is just a show/hide interaction.

The app's code is

```
define("site/mixins/interactions/reveal_content", ["exports", "jquery"], function (exports, _jquery) {

  function RevealContent($el) {
    this.el = $el;

    this.interactionData = $el.find(".interaction_data");
    this.container = $el.find(".interaction_content");
  }

  RevealContent.prototype = {
    init: function init() {
      var contentToReveal = (0, _jquery["default"])('<div />').append((0, _jquery["default"])(this.interactionData.find('td')[1]).detach());
      var initialContent = (0, _jquery["default"])('<div class="pointer" />').append((0, _jquery["default"])(this.interactionData.find('td')[0]).detach());

      this.container = this.container.parent().find('.RevealContent');

      this.container.append(initialContent);
      this.container.append(contentToReveal.hide());

      initialContent.click(function () {
        (0, _jquery["default"])(contentToReveal).slideToggle('slow');
      });

      // prevent any links within initialContent from navigating anywhere
      initialContent.find('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  };
```

I have started trying to replace the above with plain jQuery but am having a hard time decoding some of the above code, such as *(0, _jquery["default"])*

Does anyone know how I can convert above to plain jQuery, such that there is no external dependency, no required communication with the app?

Here is a jfiddle with some HTML and with the original code.

https://jsfiddle.net/0s6xdk9q/1/

Here is what I have done so far as far with the rewrite:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).on('click', '.interaction_booted', function () {
    //console.log('made it here');


        interactionData = $(this).find(".interaction_data");
        this.container = $(this).find(".interaction_content");

        var contentToReveal = $('<div />', this.container).append($(interactionData.find('tdd')[1]).detach());
        var initialContent = $('<div class="pointer" />', this.container).append($(interactionData.find('tdd')[0]).detach());

        this.container = this.container.parent().find('.RevealContent');

        this.container.append(initialContent);
        this.container.append(contentToReveal.hide());

        initialContent.click(function () {
            $(contentToReveal).slideToggle('slow');
        });

    });


});
```

Note I am using  instead of  that is because Chrome is stripping the  tags since they don't have  parent... I have confirmed that in my local page, *interactionData* and *this.container* are returning same things as the remote version of the page.

But those *contentToReveal* and *initialContent* vars are throwing me off. I just don't understand the syntax and the use of this prototype business such that I can figure out the rest of the jQuery code needed.

Does anyone knows what I need to do to get this working?

Thanks a ton!
Brian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comma here is the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). It merely evaluates the expression on the left side, followed by the right side, returning the result of right hand expression.

So what's this `(0, ...)` syntax doing here? Well it exists here to strip the function from it's parent object so it's no longer a method call, essentially unbinding `this` within the context of the method. Observe:

```js
// ECMAScript 2015
var obj = {
  foo() {
    return this;
  }
}

console.log(obj.foo() === obj);
console.log((0, obj.foo)() === obj);
```

This is a trick that Babel other transpilers use to make sure that functions imported as bare functions are called as functions and not as methods on the modules from which they are imported. In other words,

```
(0, _jquery["default"])(...)
```

Is equivalent to

```
$(...)
```

Where `$` is the jQuery function.

Comment: TIL a new old feature of the comma operator. Never knew that that was a feature of the comma separator. Cool to know.

Comment: Interesting. I had thought maybe it is so and had rewritten the original code, replacing (0, _jquery["default"]) with $ but then with original code - var contentToReveal = (0, _jquery["default"])('<div />').append((0, _jquery["default"])(this.interactionData.find('td')[1]).detach()); - that would mean $ is looking for any div, right? Otherwise how does it know context? I have a jfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/0s6xdk9q/1/ , with original code, but really curious how the code would need to be written in pure jQuery. regards, Brian

Comment: @Brian Not quite. The `$` function really is the Swiss army knife of DOM utilities. `$("div")` will select all `<div>` elements on the page, (it loosely translates to `document.getElementsByTagName("div")`), but `$("<div/>")` actually *creates* a new `<div>` element that can inserted later, e.g. with `append` (it loosely translates to `document.createElement("div")`). See the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

Comment: Wow, so much nuance! One of the things that is rally confusing is that you have this line $('<div />', this.container).append($(interactionData.find('tdd')[1]).detach()); which I suppose based on what you said means there is a div being added but when I view the page - remote or local version - I don't see any div elements created. The only change in the DOM I see is the display property of the div containing the content to hide/show. So it has been a pain figuring out what the developers really had in mind

Comment: @Brian Yes presumably `this.container` is a reference to a different document, e.g. in an iframe or on another window that was created via `window.open`. The intent of this code isn't clear to me either, so I'm not sure I could shed much more light on it other than tell you what it does.